# IEditableCollectionView & EntityFramework

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

I have a ListView data source with an ObservableCollection (Of T), where "T" is an entity of EF.
To add / edit an item, use IEditableCollectionView. It works perfectly. The problem is the cancellation of the action to modify an existing item.

```
Private Sub edit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles ListBoxMain.MouseDoubleClick

   If ListBoxMain.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("No item is selected")
        Return
    End If

    Dim editableCollectionView As IEditableCollectionView = TryCast(ListBoxMain.Items, IEditableCollectionView)

    Dim win As New ChangeItemWindow()
    editableCollectionView.EditItem(ListBoxMain.SelectedItem)
    win.DataContext = ListBoxMain.SelectedItem

    If CBool(win.ShowDialog()) Then
        editableCollectionView.CommitEdit()
    Else
        editableCollectionView.CancelEdit()
    End If

End Sub
```

The method "editableCollectionView.CancelEdit()", the following exception is thrown: "CancelEdit not supported for the current editing element."
I tried to see what gives me the property "CanCancelEdit" and is "False."

Thank you.

Comment: What is the class that implements IEditableCollectionView? Is it yours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call CanCancelEdit() to check you can CancelEdit().

To make this work, the objects in the collection need to implement IEditableObject: there is an example of how to make that happen at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject(v=vs.110).aspx

IEditableObject is mainly used for DataGridRows.

In this particular case, as you are editing one item and maybe cancelling, don't mess around with CancelEdit. Create a ViewModel class and show that in the dialog. If, and only if, the user clicks OK then copy the values back.

Your CarViewModel needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for best results in binding in the dialog...

```
dim car = ListBoxMain.SelectedItem as Car;
dim carVM as new CarViewModel
carVm.Make = car.Make
carVM.Color=car.Color}
dim win as new ChangeItemWindow()
win.DataContext = carVM
if win.ShowDialog() then
    car.Make = carVM.Make
    car.Color = carVM.Color
end if
```